# Importing presto/pyhive certificates to apache superset

Tags: apache-http-server, docker

I'm currently running apache superset inside a local docker container. The databases I am pulling from are being "hosted" on pyhive/presto. These databases require credentials/certificates that I have, but I do not know how to import them into superset.

From the official documentation: https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/docs/installation.rst#ssl-access-to-databases, there is a section about ssl access, but this hasn't been working for me. When I try this method, I'm getting an error about unexpected keyword arguments.

TLDR; I'm not really sure how to have superset recognize my certificates in a local docker container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
   "metadata_params": {},
    "engine_params": {
          "connect_args":{
              "protocol":"https",
              "requests_kwargs" : {"verify": "PATH/TO/CERTIFICATE.pem"}
        }
     }
}
```

This was the text that I placed in the "extra" field when initializing my database. The link looked like:

```
presto://username:password@rest_of_URI
```

Hope this helps anyone who runs into a similar issue!